# Javascript check if server time is greater than or less than 9am EST

Tags: javascript

I offer same day shipping if the user places an order before 9AM ET. If they place the order after 9AM, same day shipping is unavailable.

My server is using UTC time so I need to check if the time is greater than or less than 9AM ET regardless of the time where the user is located.

Not being an expert with JS, I cobbled together this code.

```
var d = new Date();
var e = d.getHours().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York' });
var f = '';

if(e >= 9) {
  f = 'shipping unavailable';
}
else {
  f = 'shipping available';
}
```

I am getting the correct result after 9AM ET on my computer but I am concerned that same day shipping will be offered after 9AM ET.

Comment: "9AM ET" is not always "9am EST" Do you mean Eastern Time generally (EDT and EST), or specifically EST? Or even better, do you specifically mean New York?

Comment: don't use a string representation - get the date in the correct timezone.

Comment: I am in South Florida, US so it would be Eastern Time generally (EDT and EST).

Comment: `var d = new Date(<?= your server time in MS since 1970 ?>);`

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm not very familiar with dates and timezones so I would not know how to rewrite the script as you suggest.

Comment: @DanielA.White - You *can't*, with `Date`, without a string. This is one of the things [`Temporal`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) will hopefully help fix.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder right theres a "better" way than `Date`.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is using `toLocaleString` on the number of hours, not on the date, so it won't even look at timezone and you'll always get back `"9"`.

This is unfortunately an area where JavaScript's standard library is really weak, something that's [actively in the process of being improved](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal).

I think for such a focussed issue (whether it's < 9 a.m. in South Florida), I'd probably manually look up the current dates when Daylight Saving Time starts and stops (for instance, [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/miami)), store them as configuration information (so you can update it the next time they change it, like they did a few years back), and then use that information to do the -4 (EDT) or -5 (EST) adjustment from `getUTCHours` as appropriate. **Very** roughly:

```
// OFF-THE-CUFF, CHECK BEFORE RELYING ON IT!
const dstDates = {
    2020: { // Year 2020
        start: new Date("2020-03-08T02:00:00-0500"),
        end:   new Date("2020-11-01T02:00:00-0400")
    },      // Year 2021
    2021: {
        start: new Date("2021-03-14T02:00:00-0500"),
        end:   new Date("2020-11-07T02:00:00-0400")
    }
    // ...with info from https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/miami?year=2021 or similar
};
const now = new Date():
const info = dstDates(now.getFullYear());
if (!info) {
    throw new Error(`Missing timezone information for ${now.getFullYear()}!`);
}
const dst = now >= info.start && now < info.end;
const hour = now.getUTCHours() - (dst ? 4 : 5);
if (hour < 9) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, use a library like [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) and keep its configuration files up to date. That would look something like:

```
const hour = moment().tz("America/New_York").hour();
if (hour < 9) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

...but for just one thing that may be a bit heavy-weight.

Just be sure to update that timezone if Florida or New York decide to make their DST rules different from one-another. (In which case, IANA would probably add a new [timezone name](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).)

Comment: a library like moment timezone can help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @T.J.Crowder. Unfortunately, I am not a JS pro and I would not know how to proceed as you suggest. Is there any way for me to simply update my current script so I can achieve the result as needed?

Comment: @Junky - Then I'd use a library as described at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggested it in comments, but got no reaction.

If I had a shop and it was important that an order received before 9AM my time could ship, then I would simply create a date object from my time as it is on my server. Like this (I am not a PHP person, so modify to match your needs on the platform you have)

Code is not tested and should be, but you get the idea.

```
<?php
  $now = new DateTime();
  $hour = $now->format('H') ?>
  $dateString =  $now->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');
  if ($hour>=9) {
    $interval = new DateInterval("P0Y0M0DT".(24-$hour)."H0M0S"); // perhaps
  }
  else {
    $interval = new DateInterval("P0Y0M0DT".(9-$hour)."H0M0S"); // perhaps (math)
  }
  $now->add($interval);
  $until = $now->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');
  
  <script>
  let currentHour = <%= $hour ?>;
  let then = new Date("<?= $until?>");
  let showTime = then.toLocaleTimeString();
  console.log(`Our shop is located in E(s)T where the time is <?= $dateString ?>,
   and you have until ${showTime} to order for shipping ${currentHour >= 9 ? "tomorrow":"today"}`);
 </script>
```

Alternatively Ajax to your server and ask the hour of day.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the followup @mplungjan.I will review but for the time being (haha) I implemented T.J. Crowder's solution.